# Calculate the percentage of change in price with reflected to previous observation, group by price type?

Tags: mysql, percentage, price

I am trying to calculate daily percentage change in price with reflected to previous observation by price type.

When I run this query, it seems to calculate the percentage change but the calculation is done from one price type to another.

I want to calculate the percentage change in price by pricetypeID.

Do you have any idea how to implement it? Any tip would be very appreciated!

```
select priceTypeID, date, price,
     if(@last_entry = 0, 0, round(((price - @last_entry) / @last_entry) * 100,2)) "percentageChange",
     @last_entry := price
     from
     (select @last_entry := 0) x,
     (select date, `t`.price, `t`.priceTypeID
     from   `t`
     order by `t`.priceTypeID, `t`.date asc) y;
order by date ASC
```

Example data is here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq57pks2d28i1j4/example.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this (add indexes to your table, otherwise it is going to be slow):

```
SELECT curr.*, 
   prev.date AS `last date`, prev.price AS `last price`,
   CONCAT(ROUND((curr.price/prev.price-1)*100,2),'%') AS `change`
FROM t curr 
    LEFT JOIN t prev 
        ON curr.priceTypeID=prev.priceTypeID 
           AND prev.date = (SELECT MAX(date) 
                            FROM t findPrev 
                            WHERE findPrev.priceTypeID=curr.priceTypeID
                              AND findPrev.date < curr.date)
ORDER BY date DESC, priceTypeID
```

Result (first rows):

[image: result]

**What it does:**

The LEFT JOIN links the table to itself. You will need that, because you want to compare current (curr) values from the same table to the previous (prev)

The subquery with the third occurrence of t as findPrev is needed to find the last date before the current date (curr.date), which would be the maximum date lower than the current.

Add indexes to `date` and `priceTypeID`. 
And add a primary key to your table.
And just to be sure, because it will mess everything up if you get it wrong: make sure your dates are in the DATE datatype, and not in the (VAR)CHAR datatype.

Add a `WHERE` if you want to make a selection, otherwise you will get the whole table, including all dates.

**Note**: Stay away from @variables in MySQL if possible. It is very hard to get reliable results with them. Sometimes it will take months before you notice that things are going wrong.